# Integral finding without "traditional" ways calculating

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$$ but I think that with the "traditional" ways would be very complicated, so I have prove that:
$$\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(a-x)dx$$
Now I have that:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\cos(x)}dx$$ but I don't know how to continue. Any ideas?

Comment: Watch what you did wrong, the answer is there. What is $f(a-x)$? Finish with  $I + I=\frac\pi2$…

Comment: $u$ substitution: $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$...

Comment: You don't correctly apply your formula. $\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

You just have to figure out another relationship between $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx $ and $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx $

[image]

Edit:

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx}= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}\, dx= \color{green}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx}\tag{1}$$

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx} +\color{green}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{2}$$

Substitute $(1)$ into $(2)$,

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx} + \color{blue}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

That is $$2I=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Let $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$$ then why it goes $I+I$ and not $I-I$? Here is where I am stacking

Comment: clearly $I-I=0$ isn't it.

Comment: I have that $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}dx$$ so why I am getting $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not $0$? So $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$$

Comment: I edited the answer, are you able to follow? Yes, the last integral that you posted in the previous comment does evaluate to zero. However, it doesn't help you in finding $I$.

Comment: ok thank you very much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

While using the result
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_0^a f(a - x) \, dx,$$
to evaluate the integral 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, dx,$$
is by far the best approach to use in this instance, it is not too hard to evaluate this particular integral using what you refer to as the “traditional” approach.

Noting that $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \cos (x - \pi/4)$, the integral can be written as
$$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{\cos (x - \pi/4)} \, dx.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x + \pi/4$ leads to
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin (x + \pi/4)}{\cos x} \, dx\\
&= \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x} \, dx\\
&= \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (\tan x + 1) \, dx\\
&= \Big{[} x - \ln (\cos x) \Big{]}_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{align*}
as expected.